# Version supported by navigational drawer in android

Tags: android

Android `Navigational Drawer` is supported on minimum which version? Also can we make `Custom Navigational Drawer` in android? If we can then kindly tell me how to get started. I have read the documentation from [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) but many things I can't understand and want help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Navigational Drawer* is part of the suport library v4.

From the [Android doc:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html)

> Support android.app classes to assist with development of applications for android API level 4 or later.

So you can use the navigation lib from **api 4** onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Its available from API 2. I believe. So almost all device. I recollect seeing it in Google IO videos.